# My dog isn't peeing or pooping and is walking funny.. What is this?

Tags: dogs, health, defecation, urination

My moms elderly aunt came in to town and started feeding my dog table food. For more information my dog was rescued so I do not know what kind of dog she was, we were told she was a cockapoo but she is 5 years old and still a tiny lap dog who's weight varies from 9-11 pounds.

I don't know if the table food has anything to do with it but she started walking funny 2-3 days ago with her back end sideways.. I just thought it was because she got excited but I seen her walking like that just past me in the kitchen or something and that's when I started to worry and realised she's sort of constipated and hasn't been pooping right and now today we noticed she isn't peeing.

I can't get into the vet near me right away. Would this be considered an emergency vet visit? Someone please help, I'm so nervous and sad.

Answer (score 2):

Any time an animal isn't peeing for more than a day, that could be a medical emergency -- starting at severe dehydration and running up thru more serious conditions. Yes I would suggest getting to a vet now rather than waiting for your usual vet to get back. (The table food may be unrelated, but it's worth reporting to the vet; not everything humans eat is dog-safe.)

If you were in the Boston area I'd suggest a visit to one of Angell Memorial's locations. They're the local SPCA's pet hospitals, and they're both very good and available 24x7x365. I've used their walk-in/ER services more than once. Not cheap but not unreasonable.